# Emgu DLL not found and Bad Image Format exceptions in Windows 8.1

Tags: .net, windows-8.1, emgucv, badimageformatexception, dllnotfoundexception

I have a .Net application using Emgu.CV v 3.1 which runs OK after being installed on Win 10 but fails on Win 8.1 64 bit with a Type Initializer exception, with an InnerException DLLNotFound for dll 'cvextern', which is installed in an x64 subfolder of the main installation folder containing the .exe. Copying the cvextern dll to the main installation folder (which has fixed the problem in the past) results in a BadImageFormat exception.

Answer (score 0):

The fix was to add the dlls msvcr120.dll and msvcp120.dll  to the folder containing cvextern.dll, which is  C:\Programs<ApplicationName>\x64. The initial InnerException should have said *DLLorComponent not found*. Perhaps Win 8.1 needs DLL components to be in the same folder as their parents.